# Error code 0x851a0019 wait on the database engine recovery handle failed sql server

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-2016

Having a problem on installing ms sql server 2016 on windows 10.
I tried on possible solutions.
uninstall sql server, remove registry, fresh installation. still end up with the same error.

Here's the errorlog:

```
2018-06-27 19:57:58.24 Server The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/name ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 63. Failure to register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually registered. 2018-06-27 19:57:59.75 spid5s External dump process return code 0x20000001. 
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      Error: 5243, Severity: 22, State: 8.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      An inconsistency was detected during an internal operation. Please contact technical support.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      Error: 5105, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
2018-06-27 19:58:01.11 spid6s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net start mssql$msdb1 /T3608
The SQL Server (MSDB1) service is starting.
The SQL Server (MSDB1) service was started successfully.


C:\Users\Administrator>sqlcmd -e
1> restore database model
2> go
restore database model

RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 0 pages in 0.101 seconds (0.000 MB/sec).
```

now the database should start

Comment: hi, its not about starting my database, I wasn't to successfully install my sql server 2016. I always got this error at the on of the installation.

Comment: was anyone able to sort this out?